# iMessage app icons dimensions

Tags: ios, xcode, icons, imessage

The app icons for iMessage applications seems to be different from the usual requested icon sizes where I know to just multiply the pixel number by 2 or 3.  For this iMessage application, its multiplying two very large numbers (the actual width x the actual height).  For example in the screenshot, the blank asks for 29 x 29 and above that it asks for both the x2 and x3 dimensions.  What is the rule of thumb when its like this?

I took a screenshot of a simple single view controller app where the app icon still references the dimensions to what I'm used to so this confirms it isn't a bug.

[image: iMessage App Icon]

[image: Single View Controller App Icon]

Comment: I did not understand the actual question. Please describe more detailed What do you mean "very large numbers"? 29 x 3?

Comment: Is that how its meant...29x3? So basically a 87 x 87 pixel icon? Then for 2x, it would be 58 x 58 pixel icon? @shallowThought

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Check [Apple Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/app-icon/). It points (pt) to pixels.